# Django websocket - path not found

Tags: python, django, websocket

I looked everywhere in Stackoverflow discussions. I can't resolve my issue with django websocket.
I'm working with React client side and Django server side. Following my code:

**asgi.py**

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from flow import consumers


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject_project.settings')

import flow.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": URLRouter(flow.routing.websocket_urlpatterns) 
})
```

**setting.py**

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'agonet_project.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}    
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'corsheaders',
        'django_celery_results',
        'django_dump_die',
        'django_extensions',
        'channels',
        'flow',
        'authentification',
    
        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'
    ]
```

**flow/consumers.py**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class MyConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None, **kwargs):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': message}))
```

**flow/routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/flow/', consumers.MyConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

**WebSocket.js**

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/flow/');

ws.onopen = () => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection opened.');
  ws.setRequestHeader('Host', window.location.host);
  // Send the message once the connection is open
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello, server!' }));
};

ws.onmessage = (event) => {
  const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
  console.log('Received message:', message);
};

ws.onclose = () => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
};

export default ws;
```

I continue to receive following message in console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/flow/' failed: WebSocket.js:1
```

and serverside:

```
Not Found: ws/flow/
[13/Jun/2023 16:53:48] "GET ws/flow/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2201
```

I can't figure it out. Other routes work well, I don't have any other issues. Please help me guys.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you dont include `"daphne",` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. This is requered to handle the asgi requests.For more indormation see the documentation  [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). This solved this problem in my case.